# this" refers to window object

Tags: javascript, this

In the BusMonitor object, "this" refers to window object thats why "name" property become global for entire script when I call BaseFunction.call(this) on BusMonitor object. I just want the BaseFunction's properties only available to BusMonitor object. How to do that ?

```
function BaseFunction() {

    this.name = "test";

}

var BusMonitor = function () {

    BaseFunction.call(this);

    return {
        init: function () {
        }
    }

}();
```

I can do it by the way below but I dont want to create object like this.

```
function BusMonitor () {

    BaseFunction.call(this);

    return {
        init: function () {

        }
    }

};

var busMonitor = new BusMonitor();
busMonitor.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, if it's possible of course, create object first and then pass it to `BaseFunction`

```
function BaseFunction() {
    this.name = "test";
}

var BusMonitor = function () {
    var obj = {
        init: function () { }
    };

    BaseFunction.call(obj);

    return obj;
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a localScope in BusMonitor to hold name value, like this:

```
function BaseFunction() {
    this.name = "test";
}

var BusMonitor = function () {
    var localScope = {};
    BaseFunction.call(localScope);
    console.log("local name:" + localScope.name);
    return {
        init: function () {
        }
    }

}();
console.log("global name: " + name);
```